# C# ListViewItem type information suppression

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, listviewitem

I'm encountering this 'strange' (for me) behavior of the `ListViewItem`. each item is surrounded by the 'type' like so: `ListViewItem: {value}`. How to get rid of the 'encapsulation of item?

The code to put items in ListView:

```
if (task.Items != null)
        {
            foreach (QuestTaskItem it in task.Items)
            {
                ListViewItem vi = new ListViewItem();
                vi.Name = it.Name;
                vi.Text = it.Name;
                vi.Tag = it;

                itemList.Items.Add(vi);
            }
        }
```

Output:
[image: The output of the code above]

**UPDATE 1** QuestTaskItem:

```
public class QuestTaskItem
{
    public int Id;
    public string Name;
    public string Data;
    public string Image;
    public int Evalutation;

    public QuestTaskItem (int id, string name, string data, string img, int eval)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
        Data = data;
        Image = img;
        Evalutation = eval;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF?

Comment: Usually this means you are adding an object with no useful ToString method. To know for sure we would need to know about the task collection.

Comment: The `it.Name` is of type `string` that's not enough?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Maybe if you post the `task` or `QuestTaskItem` we can help you more.

Comment: The Name is not the point, what you see is the Text. But where does it come from?? Do add a ToString overload to your QuestTaskItem class and/ or make sure its Name property is set properly!

Comment: Hehe. The quest continues: What do you feed into the constructor??

Comment: the values from DataRow ... strings are `ToSting()`ed and the int values are converted.

Comment: I added the overload for the ToString in the QuestTaskItem but no luck

Comment: It looks like maybe you're adding the wrong type of ListViewItem (such as System.Windows>Controls.ListViewItem). If you were to do that, the ListView would not know how to render it, and would use its ToString() method. Debug and make sure you're using the ListViewItem type from the same namespace as the ListView you're using.

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem`, the used list is `CheckedListBox`

Comment: `ListViewItem` is designed to add to the `ListView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your checkedListBox, change `itemList.Items.Add(vi);` to `itemList.Items.Add(vi.Text);`

A better way is to bind the CheckedListBox:

```
((ListBox)itemList).DataSource = task.Items;
((ListBox)itemList).DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Comment: What is the type of itemList?

Comment: System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem, the used list is CheckedListBox

Comment: This do solve the problem simingly, but I then lose ability to use the Tag property to do the processing on the item

Comment: One more time :)
The binding method makes it so you can throw out the ListViewItem entirely and directly bind to the items in your task list.

Comment: Sorry mean to set DisplayMember to Name, not Text.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111154/discussion-between-arman-and-jr-root-cs).